# getting undefined references from libssh2

Tags: c, ubuntu, ssh, libssh2

I installed the libssh2 library on my Ubuntu linux. When compiling the C code I received this message:

**undefined reference to `libssh2_session_init_ex'**

I downloaded the libssh2 from their website. I followed the instructions of how to install it on my computer but It seems i am still missing soemthing.

This is my code in my make file:

```
all: ssh
     ssh: mysshpass.c
     gcc -lssh2 -g -o mysshpass mysshpass.c

clean:
     rm -rf mysshpass
```

The include part of the C code:

```
1 #include <stdlib.h>
2 #include <libssh2.h>
3 #include <libssh2_sftp.h>
4 
5 #include <sys/socket.h>
6 #include <netinet/in.h>
7 #include <arpa/inet.h>
8 #include <sys/types.h>
9 #include <stdio.h>
10 #include <string.h>
11 
12 //#include <libssh2_config.h>
13 
14 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Thanks very much in advance

Note :

I used this new line :

```
all: ssh

ssh: mysshpass.c
    gcc -g -Lusr/src/libssh2-1.4.1/include -o mysshpass mysshpass.c
clean:
    rm -rf mysshpass
```

but still same compilations errors. By the way, I was told to install the libssh2-devel also, but i have no idea how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: It's possible you have multiple libssh2 libraries on your system, and the linker is picking up the wrong one.  SUGGESTION: Use "-L" to explicitly point to your libssh2 library.

Comment: @paulsm4: I used by same errors.                                         gcc -g -Lusr/src/libssh2-1.4.1/include -o mysshpass mysshpass.c

Comment: @Binyamin: Thanks I tried that, but not result :(. Same errors.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet is your .so/.a file in the include folder? generally not. Try `-L/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.1/`

Answer (score 1):

1) *Uninstall* what you've got.  There's something wrong, and it's being there can only confuse things.  Get rid of it.

2) *install" libssh2-dev like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2-dev libssh2
```

3) Try building your application again.

Make sure your makefile or build scripts point to the right place ("-I" for compile-time headers, "-L" for link-time libraries)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
gcc -g \
-I /usr/src/libssh2-1.4.1/include \
-L /usr/src/libssh2-1.4.1/ \
-l ssh2 \
-o mysshpass mysshpass.c
```

Comment: thanks for that. I tried it but still does not work. I was told that i need to install the libssh2-devel but the only thing i could do was download the libssh2 from www.libssh2.org.

Comment: Anyone that installed libssh2 on ubuntu if can let me know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may put -lssh at the end.
Use:

```
gcc a.c -lssh
```